# Widget : html 2 dimensional array doesn't work

Tags: widgets, html, array

I have some strange trouble with my WordPress today :

I want to store same multiple values in a widget, so I create something like this : `myCollection[id][myField]` as input's name for my admin widget form.

After a `$this->get_field_name` call and template integration, it generates the following code :

```
<label for="widget-pricetable-ibsciss-widget-2-widget-pricetable-ibscisswidget[2][box[1][price]]"> … </label>
<input id="widget-pricetable-ibsciss-widget-2-widget-pricetable-ibsciss-widget[2][box[1][price]]" value="" name="widget-pricetable-ibsciss-widget[2][box[1][price]]"></input>
```

After the submit I get this instance array from WordPress :

```
array(4) { [
  "title"]=> string(12) "Global title" 
  ["box[0"]=> array(2) { 
    ["title"]=> string(6) "title1" 
    ["price"]=> string(6) "price1" 
  } 
  ["box[1"]=> array(2) { 
    ["title"]=> string(6) "title2" 
    ["price"]=> string(6) "price2" 
  } 
  ["box_title"]=> string(9) "Box title"
```

}

And I have this strange "box[0" keys instead of a well formatted array.

Comment: Sorry, ___what___ generates that code? `get_field_name` looks a bit like ACF code but I'm guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, with a quick dirty hack I have achieve my goal :

Instead of `myCollection[id][myField]` I give to the `get_field_name`'s function something like this : `collection][id][field`.

So the generated code became :

`name="widget-pricetable-ibsciss-widget[2][box][1][title]"`

And my array just look perfect now :

```
array(3) { 
  ["title"]=> string(12) "Global title" 
  ["box"]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { 
      ["title"]=> string(6) "title1" 
      ["price"]=> string(6) "price1" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(2) { 
      ["title"]=> string(6) "title2" 
      ["price"]=> string(6) "price2" 
    } 
  } 
  ["box_title"]=> string(9) "Box title" 
}
```

PS : only for information purpose this is the get_field_name method from Wordpress :

```
function get_field_name($field_name) {
    return 'widget-' . $this->id_base . '[' . $this->number . '][' . $field_name . ']';
}
```